# printf prints too much information from array of directories in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, find, printf

The below code searches for directories that have the file **update_csgo.txt** in, writes it to an array and prints the array:

```
#!/bin/bash

mapfile -t updates < <(find /home/tcagame/ -type f -name "update_csgo.txt")
printf  "'%s' \n"${updates[@]}""
```

Here is the output I get:

```
'/home/tcagame/8frag/6/update_csgo.txt' 
/home/tcagame/update_csgo.txt'/home/tcagame/user/3/update_csgo.txt' 
/home/tcagame/update_csgo.txt'/home/tcagame/user/5/update_csgo.txt' 
/home/tcagame/update_csgo.txt'/home/tcagame/user/4/update_csgo.txt' 
/home/tcagame/update_csgo.txt'/home/tcagame/user/7/update_csgo.txt' 
/home/tcagame/update_csgo.txt'/home/tcagame/user/8/update_csgo.txt' 
/home/tcagame/update_csgo.txt'/home/tcagame/user/2/update_csgo.txt' 
/home/tcagame/update_csgo.txt
```

Where does this **/home/tcagame/update_csgo.txt** come from? What would be the best way to remove that ?

Comment: Remember this behavior. Quoted array variables, `printf` will work as intended. However `printf  "%s\n" ${updates[@]}` is also worth remembering,, as it is a slick way to print all values in the array conforming to your format string without the necessity of a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have extra quotes:

```
printf  "'%s' \n"${updates[@]}""
                              ^^
```

Removing them makes it work (optionally, you can always quote the variable itself to handle file names with spaces properly):

```
printf  "'%s' \n" "${updates[@]}"
```

Comment: Thank you :), sorry about the noob mistake.